# How to read TI's mechanical datasheets?

Tags: pcb, datasheet

I'm having difficulty interpreting the dimensions on TI's mechanical datasheet. The part below has 16 pins spaced .5mm apart. However, I cannot determine what the length and width of the pins are. Width is written as "16X 0,30/0,18" and length as "16X 0,50/0,30". I don't know what the dimensions in the numerators and denominators represent. I thought they might be uncertainties, but the values seem too large. I haven't been able to find a guide to reading the mechanical data on TI's website.

[image]

Comment: They are min/max values. +/-0.1mm or +/- 0.06mm really isn't very much.

Answer (score 1):

They are upper and lower tolerances hence "50/30" has an upper limit of 50 and a lower limit of 30.

Answer (score 1):

First, see note A: all measurements are in millimeters. A comma is commonly used in datasheets in place of a period to represent a decimal point, because it's considered easier to read. With this convention, "0,50" is 0.50mm.

The fraction represents maximum and minimum measurements: maximum / minimum.

The "16x" just means that there are 16 instances of the dimension being described.

Answer (score 1):

These are all metric pitch of 0.5mm from [1.50] divided among 3.

- so 16X 0,30/0,18" refers to max/min

  - with a computed average pad width of 0.24mm
  - or slightly LESS than half the pad pitch, presumably from etch-back

In order to prevent tolerance stack-up , this is the correct method to specify it.